# Comparing a Variable to an Array Element Not Working [Javascript]

Tags: javascript, arrays

Being new to javascript I have come across an odd issue. I have an array of elements and a variable, I want to compare that variable to all array elements and do something if they match .

Here is the snippet of code:

```
for (var i=0; i<country_arr.length; i++) {

    option_str.options[option_str.length] = new Option(country_arr[i],country_arr[i]);

    if(selected_country == country_arr[i]){
        option_str.options[i].selected = true;
    }
}
```

The array itself is an array of strings:

```
var country_arr = new Array("Republic of Ireland", "Northern Ireland");
```

For whatever reason this does not enter the if statement but oddly enough when i replace:

```
if(selected_country == country_arr[i])
```

with:

```
if(selected_country == "Republic of Ireland")
```

...it does and works perfectly.

Am I comparing the two elements incorrectly? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE - FULL .js FILE:**

Full External .js File:

```
//Create a new array, to contain the list of countries available.
var country_arr = new Array("Republic of Ireland", "Northern Ireland");
//Create a new array to hold a list of counties depending on country selection.
var s_a = new Array();
s_a[0]="";
s_a[1]="Carlow|Cavan|Clare|Cork|Donegal|Dublin|Galway|Kerry|Kildare|Kilkenny|Laois|Leitrim|Limerick|Longford|Louth|Mayo|Meath|Monaghan|Offaly|Roscommon|Sligo|Tipperary|Waterford|Westmeath|Wexford|Wicklow";
s_a[2]="Antrim|Armagh|Down|Dungannon|Derry|Tyrone";

function print_country(country_id, selected_country){
    //Given the id of the <select> tag as function argument, it inserts <option> tags
    var option_str = document.getElementById(country_id);
    option_str.length=0;
    option_str.options[0] = new Option('Select Country','');
    option_str.selectedIndex = 0;
    for (var i=0; i<country_arr.length; i++) {
        option_str.options[option_str.length] = new     Option(country_arr[i],country_arr[i]);

        if(selected_country == country_arr[i]){
            option_str.options[i].selected = true;
            print_county('county',i);
        }
    }
}

function print_county(state_id, state_index){
    var option_str = document.getElementById(state_id);
    option_str.length=0;    // Fixed by Julian Woods
    option_str.options[0] = new Option('Select County','');
    option_str.selectedIndex = 0;
    var state_arr = s_a[state_index].split("|");

    for (var i=0; i<state_arr.length; i++) {
        option_str.options[option_str.length] = new Option(state_arr[i],state_arr[i]);
    }
}
```

The function is called and the variable selected_country is set via a php file using:

```
<script language="javascript">
    var selected = <?php echo json_encode($g_country); ?>;
    print_country("country", selected);
</script>
```

Comment: Have you stepped through the loop with a debugger? Could you provide a a [complete minimally sufficient example?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: if you are not practising your javascript then use Lo-Dash lib http://lodash.com/

Comment: Where is `selected_country` set? Please post the complete code and its invocation

Comment: I have updated the post and it now contains my full .js file. I have two <select> fields in my php file one to select a country and the other a county depending on the country selected. What I what to do is set the default country in the <select> field depending on the variable $g_country. $g_country is a valid string "Republic of Ireland".

Comment: Update if i change country_arr[i] to country_arr[0] it works. Very weird but getting closer. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The issue isn't the `if` statement, but that you have an error elsewhere. *This* is what's wrong:

```
option_str.options[option_str.length] = ...
```

`option_str.length` is probably not what you meant. Try:

```
option_str.options[option_str.options.length] = ...
```

...or better yet:

```
option_str.options.push(new Option(...));
```

[Here's a working example.](http://jsfiddle.net/3QdjF/)